# Why UIImageView rotates only once?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

On button click I'm using this code line to rotate my UIImageView. But it works only once. How can I make it infinity times in every button click?

```
self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use `CGAffineTransformRotate` instead of `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation`:

```
func rotateImageView() {   
     UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.imageView.transform, CGFloat(M_PI_2))
                }) { (finished) -> Void in
                    if finished {
                        self.rotateImageView()
                    }
        }
}
```

If you want to stop it you can call:

```
self.imageView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
```

Comment: Dont use 'UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat' because at the end of the animation it resets the transform making the view jump back to its original position, it's not nice to see..